# How can I delete the div that I created from the created divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
function create() {
    $("<div class='question container' id='question' style='background-color:lavender; border:solid 15px darkcyan; height:500px; border-radius:32px'><div class='input-group' style='margin-top:10px'><input type='text' placeholder='Soru Gir...' class='form-control'/> &nbsp; &nbsp;<button class='btn btn-danger' onclick='remove()' >Sil</button>&nbsp; &nbsp;<button class='btn btn-success' onclick='createSelection()'>Şık Ekle</button></div></div></br>").insertBefore("#btn")
}

function remove() {$("#question").remove()}
```

Comment: just call the function that you created... `remove()`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn 

That's how I wipe it off. I'm creating more than one div. When I click on the button, I press the button to delete the first created the div. I want him to catch that the div and remove which button I'm pressing. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you want? There are many things about your code. Here is some:

- Don't use recurring id attributes.
- Listen event like my example. This also affects dynamically added elements.

```js
$('body').on('click', '.btn-danger', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('.question').remove();
});

$('body').on('click', '.btn-success', function(e) {
    var $quest = $(this).closest('.question');
    $quest.clone().insertAfter($quest);
});
```

```css
.question {
    background-color: lavender;
    border: solid 15px darkcyan;
    border-radius: 32px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="question container">
  <div class="input-group" style="margin-top: 10px">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Soru Gir..." class="form-control"/> &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <button class="btn btn-danger">Sil</button>&nbsp; &nbsp;
    <button class="btn btn-success">Şık Ekle</button>
  </div></br>
</div>
```

Comment: Simpler to use `$(this)` than needing the event and target for `$(e.target)`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function create() {
    $("<div class='question container' style='background-color:lavender; border:solid 15px darkcyan; height:500px; border-radius:32px'><div class='input-group' style='margin-top:10px'><input type='text' placeholder='Soru Gir...' class='form-control'/> &nbsp; &nbsp;<button class='btn btn-danger' >Sil</button>&nbsp; &nbsp;<button class='btn btn-success' onclick='createSelection()'>Şık Ekle</button></div></div></br>").insertBefore("#btn");
}
$('body').on('click','.question .btn-danger', function(){
     $(this).closest('.question').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="create" onclick="create();" />
```

Add this to your javascript code:

```
$('body').on('click','.question .btn-danger', function(){
     $(this).closest('.question').remove();
});
```

Comment: That's how I wipe it off. I'm creating more than one div. When I click on the button, I press the button to delete the first created the div. I want him to catch that the div and remove which button I'm pressing. How can I do that?

Comment: Not working. You know what I want to do? I want to erase the div I want to erase and I want it erased. I don't want to start deleting the first created div.

Comment: Bilal bey, there was a typo I had closeset , instead of closest, i corrected it

Comment: It did not. Not working. Is there an error in the code?

Comment: $("#question").empty()

Comment: Waiting for the demo.

Comment: please check the answer, and demo

Comment: This works. Thank you so much. But I want to ask another problem this time. The page stays below when I delete the div. Can every div deleted page pull up the page? How do I get a div that is on top instead of a deleted div?

Comment: Can I also click on the Save button instead of the div I removed up to the location? Can all divs be deleted when they are first?